# Is there a way to specify a dynamic report filename in package.json file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am creating a report for the test cafe cases. Can it be a dynamic path?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a path for the generated report using [programmatic interface](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402656/reference/testcafe-api/runner/reporter#save-the-report-to-a-file)
or [command-line interface](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#-r-nameoutput---reporter-nameoutput).